# SQL Query problems

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `userRatings` with a field called `userNumber` (int), `userRating` (int), and `userRatingDateTime` (datetime).

I have a second table named `userProfiles` with a field called `userNumber` (int), userGender (int).

What I'm trying to do is this:

I want to query all `userNumbers` along with the total sum of their `userRating`, where `userGender` = 1 (represents female), but only in the last week.  (In other words, ratings from beyond one week ago should not be totaled.)

I have tried many different approaches to this problem but I never seem to get it right.  Currently my syntax involves nesting one SELECT in another, but it's not yielding what I want - not even close - so I won't bother sharing it.

Can someone with a little more SQL experience help me with this one?  Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You tagged your question with SQL Server (the DBMS from Microsoft) **an** MySQL.

Comment: My bad.  I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this::

```
Select
ur.userNumber,
SUM(userRating) as totalRating,
userGender
from userRatings ur
inner join userProfiles up on (ur.userNumber  = up.userNumber )
where up.userGender=1
AND userRatingDateTime<DATEDIFF(now() INTERVAL 7 DAYS)

 GROUP BY  ur.userNumber
```